# How is this question duplicate?

Tags: discussion

I asked for substitute for a graph plugin which happens to not work on an IE-8.

I did my research and I know why it's not working, So i asked for substitutes as I am not aware of way out.

Question gets closed as duplicate, when it's not a duplicate, please explain how it's duplicate, is the other question asking for substitute too ?

You may close the question for any reason but not duplicate here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24162636/substitue-of-this-graph-for-ie-8

Comment: So you are not receiving the same scripting errors as in the duplicate?

Comment: @Stijn I didn't asked for why I am getting this error or why it's not working... my question was for finding a substitute

Comment: Looks like it should have been closed for requesting an offsite resource or library.

Comment: Closing as a duplicate actually looks like a better deal to me, since it doesn't leave the questioner without any information.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi sorry I didn't get you

Comment: @Customized, well, the duplicate contains information about making your graph API compatible with IE8. It may be useful to you if you decide to go that route instead of using a substitute. The other, arguably more legitimate, close reason, "requesting a preferred resource or library", would have left you with no information at all.

Comment: @DanielKelley I agree.

Comment: @CustomizedName Another library wouldn't make a difference from what I understand, the problem is d3.js itself not working with IE 8.

Answer (score 5):

It **is** a duplicate. Look at the code you are using:

[image]

you state it isn't working in IE8. Now look at the title of the target question:

[image]

The rule with duplicates is that the question can be asked quite differently *but the answer is still the same* - this is why Bergi marked it as a duplicate of that particular question.

Answer (score 3):

Even if it weren't a duplicate (A gold badge'd person marked it as such, so I'll defer to their judgment), it'd still be off topic:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.