# Is asking how your question is duplicate in meta is a bad question itself?

Tags: discussion

Maybe it's my bad day or perhaps someone's else...

Closed my question which was not duplicate as duplicate, if it's off-topic, it should be closed as off-topic so that I can improve it.

I asked a question in Meta so that I find the reason why it's closed and fix the issue, but getting negative votes for it, but why ?

[How is this question duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260173/how-is-this-question-duplicate)

**Question: Is asking how your question is duplicate in meta is a bad question itself ?**

Comment: But is asking why the meta-question you asked about how your question was a duplicate was downvoted a bad question?

Comment: `it should be closed as off-topic so that I can improve it.`.... you can still improve it and explain why it isn't a duplicate and correct the issue that would also make it off-topic.  There is nothing stopping you from improving

Answer (score 5):

No it's not a bad question, I have seen many cases where actions have been reversed because of a question like this in Meta.

The negative votes are because people are not agreeing with the premise of your Meta question. They are harmless, they do not affect your rep level at all.

Before you toodle off to youtube check out the introductory post [*How does Meta Stack Overflow work?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/259917/109702), it has a section on voting (and incidentally a paragraph on closing as duplicate).